# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier using JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, ag-grid

I am trying to use ag-Grid to display some data onto a table using MSSQL. My issue is when I `console.log(JSON.stringify(field1))` on the **server side** it shows me:

`recordset:[ { field1 : 'Alexandra.Bernhard' }, { field1 : 'Andrew.Collins' }],`.

However, when i try the same thing on the client side, I receive an error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

**router.js**

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      var field1 = await conn.query("SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 Names FROM Table1");
      JSON.stringify(field1) 
      console.log(field1) //recordset:[ { Resource_Email_ID: 'Alexandra.Bernhard' }, { Resource_Email_ID: 'Andrew.Collins' }],
      res.render('index', {field1: field1});
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message)
    }
  });
```

**index.ejs**

```
var obj = "<%- JSON.stringify(field1) %>" //[object, Object]

var columnDefs = [{headerName: "Names", field: "name"}];
    // specify the data
    var rowData = [{name : obj}];

    // let the grid know which columns and what data to use
    var gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: columnDefs,
      rowData: rowData
    };
```

How can I get the actual values to display in the table?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` returns the string, you need to assign it to something.

Comment: I have fixed it! Thank you.

Comment: Where did you fix it? Edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put quotes around it. `JSON.stringify()` produces a JavaScript literal, you need to substitute that to assign the object to the variable.

```
var obj = <%- JSON.stringify(field1) %>
```

Comment: `ag-Grid: rowData must be an array, however you passed in a string. If you are loading JSON, make sure you convert the JSON string to JavaScript objects first`. This is what ag-Grid spits, if I put in single quotes

Comment: Then don't put it in quotes.

Comment: I'm not, was telling you the error I received following your suggestions.

Comment: You did put it in quotes. I changed the quotes from double quotes to single quotes, then you got a different error. So I corrected the answer to say not to put it in any quotes at all.

Comment: I had made the changes on my end, but forgot to update it here.

Answer (score -1):

It was a simple fix, I had to pass in `obj` into rowData variable and remove the double quotes.

```
var obj = <%- JSON.stringify(field1) %> 
var columnDefs = [{headerName: "Distinct_Names", field: "obj"}];
    // specify the data
    var rowData = obj;
```

Comment: What is `Names`? Where are you using the `obj` variable?

Comment: I had it named differently. But that's where the `obj` var gets passed, into the rowData.